# An error occurred while installing racc (1.7.1), and Bundler cannot continue

Tags: ruby, arm, clang, shopify

I'm trying to use the shopify-cli to build app extensions, but its failing somewhere deep in my system.

```
1 warning generated.
linking shared-object racc/cparse.bundle
ld: can't link with a main executable file
'/Users/username/.rubies/ruby-3.2.2/bin/ruby' for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [cparse.bundle] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2
```

I've tried reinstall ruby, and switching versions and reinstalling the shopify-cli. But nothing has worked.

I'm on an M1 mac using `arm` but the error says it can't link for `architecture x86_64` how can I get it to use arm?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my node version was using `x86`. Installing a new version of node and it works perfectly. Double check the arch your running the command from!

Comment: Which node version were you using and which new version did you install?

Comment: I think I was on 16 and I installed 20. But it wasn't about the node version. It was because when I installed node I was running `x86` (an old Macbook Pro) so when I upgraded to an M1 chip without reinstalling node it was still installed for intel. I think reinstalling any version of node would have worked.